# How to display external HTML with scroll and zoom (pinch) capabilities?

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs

I have been struggling with this issue for days now. I am implementing an application for Android and iOS using Sencha Touch. I want to be able to click on a link (a list item) which can point to a html or an image or maybe even PDF documents (for iOS). This file can be either local or on another domain.

I have found two different approaches so far, but haven't got any of them to work perfect. One approach is to change "window.location" and go to a html page containing a frame with a back button and another frame with the file I want to display. Scrolling and zooming works fine but when the user wants to go back the whole application has to be reloaded (all javascript files and so on..).

The other approach is to fetch the desired file using an ajax request and add the response text inside a panel. The problem with this is that the zooming is not working. I tried to listen for a pinch event and then scale the panel but then the scrolling stops working...

So the question is: How do i display external content such as HTML pages and pictures but still preserve the scroll and zoom capabilites and allow the user to go back without having to reload the whole application again?

I am grateful for all information i can get! /Christian

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PhoneGap, you can try to the ChildBrowser plug-in: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

For a pure mobile web app, use the HTML5 cache manifest to avoid reloading when you move between frames and pages: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html

Comment: Then I have to deploy the application using PhoneGap. I want the app to work even without PhoneGap.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your apps onCreate() method:

```
WebSettings settings = this.appView.getSettings();
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

It won't work if your ROM does not support mulit-touch but since it is already working in your browser this should do it.